# Firebase: How to get a list of all child nodes?

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, pyrebase

How am I able to get a list of the child nodes in my realtime database?

This is what my database looks like:

[image: This is what my database looks like]

```py
firebase = pyrebase.initialize_app(config)
database = firebase.database()

author = ctx.message.author
now = datetime.now()

data = {
    'Submit by': f'{author.name}#{author.discriminator}',
    'Date': now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S CET")
}

database.child(str(username)).set(data)
```

So I'm trying to get a list that would look like `[user1, user2, user3, user4]`.

Answer (score 1):

put it in a varaible like this:

```
nodes = database.child('nameOfChild').get().val()
```

if you want just the nodes names you can do this:

```
nodes = database.child('nameOfChild').get().val().keys()
```